# Как отменить переход на новую строку при нажатии enter?

Tags: c#, winforms

Помогите, нужно, чтобы при нажатии клавиши enter сообщение из textbox'а отправлялось, а в самом textboxe'е курсор не переходил на новую строку

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Подпишитесь на событие `KeyDown`:

```
private void textBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        e.SuppressKeyPress = true;

        // отправка сообщения
    }
}
```